# change color in navbar based on what html page is active

Tags: html, css

Hi guys I have a shared layout navbar with white color text.
I happen to have a few other pages the user can visit but the background on them is very bright.

I dont want to change the background.
I want to change the navbar color but only on those selected pages, 
can I do this in CSS?
Changing the color is not the problem, the problem is changing the color on only a few specific pages

Hope this make sense. I don't mind if its in javascript while I prefer CSS

so if I were to write pseudo code.

```
#myNavbar 
{
color: white;
}

if(source == gallery.html || contact.html)
{
#myNavbar{

color:red; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have this kind of logic with `css`, but you can achieve this with `javascript` like this:

```
var currentUrl = document.location.href; // get URL from browser. You should add your PATH TO the files on the condition.
if (currentUrl !== 'PATH_TO/gallery.html' || currentUrl !== 'PATH_TO/contact.html') {
  document.querySelector('#myNavbar').setAttribute('style' 'color: red;');
}
else {
  document.querySelector('#myNavbar').setAttribute('style' 'color: white;');
}
```

You should wrap this with [some onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) function. And you can read about the document.location [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location).

Hope that help!